# Submit PHP query with Python

Tags: php, python, html

I want to download lot of documents from website. There is download button in front of each document. I checked downloading url from that button. It is something like:

```
http://example.com/download.php?id=XYZ
```

Where XYZ is ranging from say 1 to 100. When I tried putting this url in separate tab, it redirected to homepage instead downloading file. It looks like original url is masked behind PHP query (Just *noob* assumption :P). I tried using python's '**BeautifulSoup**' library to get these downloading links and '**request**' library to do PHP get query. So far I am not able to do it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use the developer tools, check the cookies sent to the server and other headers. They might impose restriction base on cookies, session or referer.

Comment: p/s: Get request is not specific to PHP but a standard http request.

Comment: Someone suggested me to use [Selenium Browser](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) but I was not able to automate it.